# Other ways to share information on ELU

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This ["evil spelling test" question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88427/evil-spelling-test-what-makes-a-word-hard-to-spell-orally) was closed as not constructive. But the question brought up matters of interest to some people who frequent this site (English spelling, spelling in context), and Barrie England's answer (which he admits is "Perhaps not an answer") also leads the interested reader to a compelling new source.

It seems to me there is still a place for this sort of question on this site. I've seen it before -- questions I found nifty get closed because they don't fit within the guidelines. I'm sure that once a question is closed it is less likely to be read.

My question here is, is there a place for "questions" like this one, perhaps a "links" or "discussion" section where these kinds of resources can be shared and talked about in a non Q&A format? Is this something that would interest users of this site? It would certainly interest me.

Someone is going to reply with, "that's what the internet is for; don't clutter up this site with information you can find elsewhere." Fair enough. But I wouldn't have known to go looking for an "evil spelling test." It took someone else, with a prior interest and access to that information, to bring it to my attention. I frequent this site because I am fascinated by other people's questions, observations and knowledge. I don't have the time to go wandering around the internet looking for things that might interest me. Neither, probably, do you.

Comment: I should add that I don't think "chat" would work well for this either -- it is too informal and unstructured.

Comment: A blog post perhaps?

Comment: As I write, the "evil spelling test" you linked to already has 319 comments. I don't know how many (if any) are from you, JAM, but surely that would be a good place to look for discussion of the particular subject.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've been trying to figure out how your comment is relevant. My question is not about that particular discussion; it uses the question that points to that discussion as an example.

Comment: @KitFox - yes, perhaps. Good blog material might be found in closed questions that generated good answers or discussions in the comments. If your comment were an answer I'd accept it.

Comment: There's the ELU blog, as well as [Language Log](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/) (which has provided the answers to many potential questions I've had so they were never posted to ELU). A quick Google search will yield several linguist and English language blogs and every year there is usually a "Top 10" or "Top 25" list released by bloggers and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Closed questions can also be deleted, but many of them aren't.  In that sense, a closed (but not deleted) question does serve as an archive of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

The [chat room for EL&U](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95) is the right place for questions that would not be a good fit on the main site. If then you have an idea for a blog post, you can discuss about that on the [EL&U Blog](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1063) chat room.

Chat rooms are not so restrictive about what it is acceptable, and it is the right place for discussions. If the topic of a discussion can also be the topic of a blog, you can discuss the topic in the right chat room.